# saving json value to mysql

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i have json file, and the content is list country
but when i save to my database, just the first sentence
example if i save "united states", in the database just "united"
i hope to save all, but i can't

```
var url_country="<?=base_url()?>country.json";
var negara_list ="<option value=''></option>";
    $.getJSON(url_country, function(data) {
      $.each(data,function(key,val){
         negara_list += "<option value="+val+">"+val+"</option>";
      });
      $(".negara").html(negara_list);
  });
```

[this is the structur database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbzM6.png)

and this is function to save in database

```
$form=$this->input->post('form');
    $data=array(
        'NIS'                 =>$form['nis'],
        'NISN'                =>$form['nisn'],
        'NAMA_LENGKAP'        =>$form['nama_lengkap'],
        'KEWARGANEGARAAN'     =>$form['kewarganegaraan'],
        'BAHASA'              =>$form['bahasa']
    );
    if($this->model->cekNis($form['nis'])->num_rows()==0 && $form['nisn']!=''){
        $this->db->insert('m_siswa',$data);
        $d['status']=1;
        $d['keterangan']='data berhasil dimasukan';
    }else{
        $d['status']=0;
        $d['keterangan']="data sudah pernah di tambahkan sebelumnya";
    }
    $d['data']=$data;
    $this->json($d);
```

Comment: show us your DB structure it might be size issue or something else

Comment: can you show your save country function?

Comment: show me your $_POST data in var_dump($_POST); before the insert it to database

Comment: post sample json

Comment: what is `$this->input->post('form')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to encapsulate the `val` input value with quotes so it's sending the whole string :

```
negara_list += "<option value='"+val+"'>"+val+"</option>";
```